# PHP reg ex allow all letters in all alphabets

Tags: php, regex

I want to create a reg expression in PHP to allow all letters in all alphabet including Cyrillic, Greek Chinese etc and also allow numbers, dot and underscore. First three characters must be letters (all alphabets).

This will be used to validate a username so no spaces.

```
$regex = \p{L}\;
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I don't have any experience in regular expressions sorry. How can I create this reg ex?

Comment: Do you need to match any words? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: It will be used to validate a username. so no spaces

Comment: @rexhin There is a shortcut for no-space : \S

Comment: I am marking this down because reading the comments the exact criteria of the regex you need is changing and is not clearly declared on the question; you're asking for a biscuit and taking a cake.

Comment: @Martin: Though I am not a native speaker, I love the cake Image. Brilliant, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could come up with:

```
$username = 'äöäölöäßµ';
$regex = '~^\p{L}{3}[\p{L}\w]*[\p{L}\d]$~u';
if (preg_match($regex, $username)) {
   // it matches
}
```

See a demo on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kY3jZ4/3) additionally.
This allows only letters (of any alphabet) for the first three characters and letters, digits and underscores up to the end. Only a digit or letters are allowed for the last character.

Comment: does this allow only numbers dots and underscore?

Comment: @rexhin: This only allows letters (no underscores or digits). Please be more precise on what you need, the regex can be adjusted.

Comment: Can you modify it to use only letters numbers and underscore after the third char?

Comment: So: first three letters must be only letters in any alphabet. after the third character only letters numbers dots and underscore should be allowed

Comment: please can you do it to end only in letter or number? so it can not end with an underscore or dot? I will accept as an answer after this.

Comment: @rexhin why don't you take the example given by Jan, and then using https://www.regex101.com work with that example and ***learn*** from it as well as tailoring the result to your specific (and seemingly ever changing) needs. Jan is not here to do your work for you. Learn for yourself.

Comment: sure I will. Thank you

Comment: @rexhin: See the last updated answer and the explanation. Please be more precise next time in the fist place though :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not include all the requirements in the questions because I thought no one will read it. Im so sorry and thank you so much

Comment: hey @Jan. this returns always false for any string I insert can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem to solve and I seem to have finally struck gold here at stackoverflow. But the solution from Jan is not entirely correct, because country-specific characters must always be encoded in Unicode (UTF-8 or higher). But with UTF-8 or higher, no preg functions of PHP works absolutly correct. Then the mb_ereg functions must be used. However, the regular expression also works perfectly with mb_ereg_match, although the delimiters `~` and the modifier `u` have to be omitted (POSIX syntax).

And I also noticed a small flaw, although it must be said at this point that I am super-picky. :-)
"Curl-fonts" (Arabic, Japanese, Chinese, etc.) naturally also recognize digits that are not intercepted by the regExp. For example, a username "二つつのキラビアンカ" would be permitted, although a digit at the beginning is not permitted. But "二つ" (Japanese) stands for the people living in Europe more common digit 2 (the whole in Latin characters: "2Kira-Bianca"). Although I have to admit that I'm not able to use any of these "curl-fonts" and do not know whether these characters really equivalent to our digit 2 or the written two.

Finally, briefly on the expression "curl-fonts" that I used. This is in no way meant to be derogatory, but I haven't another idea, what I can used as general term for these writings. Conversely, our Latin letters are also just curls for people, which don't master these letters.